# Who are "they" here?

Tags: tenet

Protagonist watches through peep hole from truck, which
carrying Protagonist, Neil and wounded Kat:

> Protagonist:  Shit. **They** didn't take us inside.
>
> Neil: What do we do?
>
> Protagonist: We use the breach. The chaos right after impact. Get
> ready.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotas (the shipping company) evidently has elements that are both inside and outside the airport's "*airside boundary*". Neil and the Protagonist have secreted themselves in a shipping container that they hope came from inside the boundary, and hence that they will be dropped close to the vault, subjectively after the "plane accident" had taken place.

Unfortunately for them, what actually happened is that the cargo crate didn't come from inside the boundary, but outside. They're forced to improvise an entrance during the accident, rather than being able to take advantage of the aftermath.

The "they" are the airport cargo loading staff.